# How much does the Meridional Overturning Circulation strengthen the Gulf Stream?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, ocean-currents

While the Gulf Stream is a [western boundary current](http://oceanmotion.org/html/background/western-boundary-currents.htm) (WBC), one professor told me that the Gulf Stream is stronger than it should be just by using theoretical calculations of WBC. How much is the heat+volume flux of the Gulf Stream increased by the existence of the MOC?

Comment: I only come across Meridional Overturning **Circulation**, but not current.  If I understand you right, you're suggesting the Gulf Stream is stronger because of the transport of energy from other areas by the MOC?

Comment: Might I suggest you reach out to that professor for a better answer!